# Moq expectations on the same method twice in a row

Tags: c#, testing, moq

I am trying to set up exceptions for a method that is called twice in a row with different parameters. Like this:

```
  var adapter = new Mock<IKeyAdapter>();
  adapter.Setup(x => x.ImportKey(It.IsAny<Guid>(), key, It.IsAny<string>(), publicTicket)).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
  adapter.Setup(x => x.ImportKey(It.IsAny<Guid>(), key, It.IsAny<string>(), privateTicket)).Returns(Guid.Empty);
```

I wan't the first to pass and the second to fail. Currently it seems that the second setup overwrites the first.

Is this possible with Moq?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct that the second expectation is overwriting the first. This appears to be a current limitation. Some workarounds have been devised as follows:

- [**Moq Sequences**](http://dpwhelan.com/blog/software-development/moq-sequences/) which can obtained [**here**](https://github.com/dwhelan/Moq-Sequences) at github.
- Overloading `IExpect.Returns` to take an expression rather than a value as described [**here**](http://madprops.org/blog/moq-triqs-successive-expectations/), and elaborated on [**here**](http://www.timvw.be/2009/03/14/setup-expectation-with-successive-function-calls-using-moq/) and [**here**](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/29/moq-sequences.aspx).

Comment: Nice. Much more readable than the state-flag-and-conditional that I cooked up when I faced the same problem.